# How to create a 2 dimensional array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, integer

I want to create a 2 dimensional array in C that will be filled with values from a text file. These values are integers and contain 5 rows by 10 columns. Each integer is separated by a space and each column by an end of line.

I am using `int[ , ] xxx = new int[5,10];`

I am getting 9 errors, ranging from C2143, C3409, C2059. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're trying to use C++ constructs (`new`) in a C program.

Comment: `int[ , ] xxx = new int[5,10];` is definitely not valid C syntax. You can't make up things like that.

Comment: When searching for a C tutorial, it is best to avoid C++ tutorials.  Of course, your code isn't valid in either language....

Comment: Your syntax looks more like C#.  C is a very different language but I'm afraid, you cannot learn it from scratch without following a good book or tutorial just by asking questions.

Comment: read basics of `array`

Answer (score 2):

If you can do it with a compile time allocation and you don't need the pointer then:

```
int x[5][10];
```